# Forwarded kerberos tickets cached in /tmp instead of keyring

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, kerberos

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04.  They're configured to cache kerb tickets in the kernel keyring via this setting in the `[libdefaults]` section of `/etc/krb5.conf`:

```
default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
```

This works fine if I `kinit` (tickets do get cached in the keyring).  However if I  forward a ticket to the box when I ssh to it (using GSSAPIDelegateCredentials), the ticket gets cached in the `/tmp` directory.

I have tried setting the following in the `[domain/company.org]` section of `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`

```
krb5_ccname_template = KEYRING:persistent:%U
```

as suggesting in sssd man page but it has no effect.

How can I get forwarded tickets to be cached in the kernel keyring and not `/tmp`?